# implementing binary search tree insertion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, insert, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing the insert function of a BST, below is my code:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
    deriving (Show, Eq)

tinsert             :: Tree a -> a -> Tree a 
tinsert Empty a         = Branch a Empty Empty
tinsert (Branch a left right) b
    | b == a = Branch a left right
    | b < a = Branch a (tinsert left b) right
    | b > a = Branch a left (tinsert right b)
```

When I was loading this function in ghci, it gave me many errors, which seem to be related to the comparison parts. I don't see any problem with it. I'm new to Haskell, could anybody help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add the details of the error messages you are getting and what you've tried to fix them.

Comment: Since you are comparing the objects inside the tree, they must be members of the `Ord` typeclass. The type of `<` is `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`. The correct type for your function would be `Ord a => Tree a -> a -> Tree a`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changing the type of `tinsert` to

```
tinsert :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
```

fixes it.

This is necessary because the functions `(<)` and `(>)` are from the `Ord` typeclass, and you need to own up to that in the type signature.

You also use `==` and `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, but `Eq` is a superclass of `Ord`, so the compiler knows that if you have `(<)` available you already have `==`, so you don't need to say `Eq a` as well.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks a lot, but it's actually tinsert :: (Ord a) =》 Tree a -> a -> Tree a. I fixed it. Thanks for the info.